# GPU not used on d3rlpy

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am new to using d3rlpy for offline RL training and makes use of pytorch. So I installed cuda 1.16 as recommended from [PYtorch doc](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/): `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116`. I installed d3rlpy after and run the following sample code:

```
from d3rlpy.algos import BC,DDPG,CRR,PLAS,PLASWithPerturbation,TD3PlusBC,IQL
import d3rlpy
import numpy as np
import glob
import time

#models
continuous_models = {
                      "BehaviorCloning": BC,
                      "DeepDeterministicPolicyGradients": DDPG,
                      "CriticRegularizedRegression": CRR,
                      "PolicyLatentActionSpace": PLAS,
                      "PolicyLatentActionSpacePerturbation": PLASWithPerturbation,
                      "TwinDelayedPlusBehaviorCloning": TD3PlusBC,
                      "ImplicitQLearning": IQL,
                    }
#load dataset data_batch is created as a*.h5 file with d3rlpy
dataset = d3rlpy.dataset.MDPDataset.load(data_batch)
        
# preprocess
mean = np.mean(dataset.observations, axis=0, keepdims=True)
std = np.std(dataset.observations, axis=0, keepdims=True)
scaler = d3rlpy.preprocessing.StandardScaler(mean=mean, std=std)

# test models
for _model in continuous_models:
    the_model = continuous_models[_model](scaler = scaler)
    the_model.use_gpu = True
    the_model.build_with_dataset(dataset)

    the_model.fit(dataset = dataset.episodes,
                  n_steps_per_epoch = 10800, 
                  n_steps = 54000,
                  logdir = './logs', 
                  experiment_name = f"{_model}", 
                  tensorboard_dir = 'logs',
                  save_interval = 900, # we don't want to save intermediate parameters
                 )
    #save model
    the_timestamp = int(time.time())
    the_model.save_model(f"./models/{_model}/{_model}_{the_timestamp}.pt")
```

The issue is that None of the models, despite being set with `use_gpu =True` are actually using the GPU. With a sample code of pytotch and testing `torch.cuda.current_device()` I can see that pytorch is properly set and detecting the gpu. Any idea where to look for solving this issue? I am not sure this is a bug from the d3rlpy so I would bother creating an issue on github yet :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing `use_gpu = True` as an argument along with `scaler = scaler`. `the_model` object has no method called `use_gpu` like `build_with_dataset`.